# Open viewController file from every Viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, e-commerce

I am developing e-commerce application very similar like Flipkart.

Now I can visit my application without login. I mean initially I can skip login. But when I am going to purchase any item user should be be prompted to login.

Now client's requirement is there should be login button at every page of the application so, user should be navigated to login page from every page and after successfully login he should return to perticular page from when he/she went to login page.

Any idea how can I achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: How about creating the login view controller (or having it as a singelton) when user tapps login button and presenting a modal on the current view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fahim's solution is also working but it has one limitation that I have to create login button on navigation bar. I can't put login button anywhere in the screen.

I approached differently.

1. I have created loginViewController.
2. Create protocol in loginViewController file.
3. Put button in every viewcontroller to open loginviewcontroller file
4. Modally open loginview controller

Most important thing is in my Stroryboard file I took loginviewcontroller file embedded in NavigationController and my NavigationController is modally attached with every ViewController.

[image]

**In LoginViewController.h**

```
@class LoginViewController;
@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)LoginViewControllerViewDidCancel:(LoginViewController *)controller;
- (void)LoginViewControllerViewDidDone:(LoginViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak)id <LoginViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**In LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)didCancel:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.delegate LoginViewControllerViewDidCancel:self];
}
- (IBAction)didDone:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate LoginViewControllerViewDidDone:self];
}
```

Now same code for FirstViewController, SecondViewController etc.

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
@interface FirstViewController ()<LoginViewControllerDelegate>

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LoginView"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
        loginViewController.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Thirdpage"]) {

    }
}

#pragma loginViewController delegate
-(void) LoginViewControllerViewDidCancel:(LoginViewController *)controller{

    //Your Logic
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) LoginViewControllerViewDidDone:(LoginViewController *)controller{
    //Your Logic
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It works for me like a charm..

Comment: **I can't put login button anywhere in the screen.**, *I will say you can... just change the frame size & rest I will update my answer...*

Comment: *Put button in every viewcontroller to open loginviewcontroller file* is the worst part... that means you will write `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {` in all controller.m... **Right?**

Answer (score 1):

> Step 1 : Create Base class

***BaseViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
-(void)takeMeToLogin;
@end
```

***BaseViewController.m***

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface BaseViewController () {
    UIView *myTabBar;

    UIButton *loginButton;
}

@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    loginButton.tag = 5566778897;
    [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takeMeToLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [loginButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, width, height);
    [self.view addSubview:backButton];
}

-(void) takeMeToLogin {
    // code here to go to Login screen
}
```

> Step 2: Use BaseViewController as your base class.

Now whenever you create any class, you will have as below.

```
@interface YourViewController : BaseViewController
```

By default you will have `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController`

***Let me know if you need anything else***

---

### Edit 1

***Regarding your comment,*** *Fahim's solution is also working but it has one limitation that I have to create login button on navigation bar. I can't put login button anywhere in the screen.*, ***I will say, you can add it anywhere you want***. *Below is how.*

In `YourViewController.m` have below.

```
UIButton *buttonThatYouWantToMove = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:5566778897];
[self.view addSubview:buttonThatYouWantToMove]; // if this don't work use insertSubview:aboveSubview:
buttonThatYouWantToMove.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height); // this is very important
```

Done!!!

*Let me know if you need further explanation.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd create `MYBaseViewController` and inherit from it in all other controller. I'd create a function which adds login button to navbar right item and a function which handles the login. This way, you'll keep everything in one place.

You can do the same in `UIViewController` category and call the methods in proper controllers, but personally I think that if that's solution for every single `UIViewController` it's less pretty.

If someone has better idea, I'd gladly hear about it.